# ExtJS alias vs id

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I don't understand the usage of [alias](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-alias) vs id vs itemId config properties in ExtJS

*app/view/foo.js*

```
Ext.define('app.view.foo', {
    ...
    alias: 'widget.foo',         // 1
    id: 'foo',                   // or 2
    ...
});
```

*app/controller/goo.js*

```
Ext.define('app.controller.goo', {
    ...
    views: ['foo', ...],
    init: function() {
        this.control({
               'foo': {...},     // 1
               '#foo': {...}     // or 2
               ...
        });
        ...
    },
    ...
});
```

With `alias` I can use `xtype` easily.. but what advantage do I gain by setting `id`'s to my views?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `alias` is set on the class *definition*, using `Ext.define`, and is what is used for the `xtype` when creating instances (you seem to have the hang of this).  An `id` should be set on a class *instance*, e.g. when using `Ext.create`.  This just serves as a unique identifier for a particular instance of a component.

FWIW, `id` should be used sparingly.  You are much better served using `itemId` and referencing components relatively using that, rather than globally with an `id`.

Comment: Makes sense. And I'm assuming ExtJS has a native id generator to help out?

Comment: ExtJS will assign a unique ID to every component it creates, unless you specify the `id` in the config options when instantiating.

Comment: Yes, if memory serves, the native ExtJS id generator is Ext.id()