# Dynamically add Text Fields to a Panel in extjs

Tags: json, extjs, dynamic, panel

I have a Panel where in I wish to add two text fields in 'hbox' layout for every entry in the json data.
For e.g. : Suppose I have a json like this:

```
{
    ..
    ids : [
        {
            'name' : 'first name',
            'surname' : 'first surname',
        },
        {
            'name' : 'second name',
            'surname' : 'second surname'
        }
    ]
}
```

In this example the panel will consist of two rows of two textfields each with the labels being 'name' and 'surname'

So in the for loop I need to know how to insert the two textfields in 'hbox' layout inside the Panel. Had it been a grid it would be easy to add to the store.

Here's what I have done.

```
Ext.getCmp('panelid').items.add(Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
                                        layout: {
                                            type: 'hbox'
                                        },
                                        defaults: {
                                            bodyPadding: 10,
                                            margin: '10 0 10 10',
                                            height: 100
                                        },
                                        items: [
                                        {
                                            fieldLabel: 'Name',
                                            id: 'idFieldName',
                                            name : 'Data',
                                            margin:'0 10 10 0',
                                            width:225,
                                            labelWidth: 40
                                        },
                                        {
                                            fieldLabel: 'Datatype',
                                            name : 'Type',
                                            id: 'idFielddataType',
                                            margin: '0 10 10 0',
                                            width:225,
                                            labelWidth:55
                                        }
                                        ]
                                    }));
```

**EDIT1:** Added my progress.

**EDIT2:** I have found half the solution to the problem. The problem was that I don't need to add to the items but rather I can just add to the panel itself. So this is working :

```
Ext.getCmp('panelid').add(....)
```

But now the issue is that in the second iteration of the loop the next hbox formatted text fields come on TOP of the existing ones, i.e., instead of adding a row below this line is adding on top of the panel. Kindly advise how to get rid of this issue.

**EDIT 3:** 
I have found the solution as to why it was adding elements on top of the existing ones. It's because whenever I was adding elements in the loop the id of the added elements was same. So in effect it was replacing the two textfields I had already put in the previous iteration.

So, I have just altered the id name as follows:

```
id: 'idFieldName' + i
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @RianSchmits I have edited the post. Please check

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the "form" layout instead (or an Ext.form.Panel), and use a Ext.form.FieldContainer to group your 2 text field.
Example :

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'FieldContainer Example',
    width: 550,
    bodyPadding: 10,

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            fieldLabel: 'first line',
            labelWidth: 100,
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                flex: 1
            }]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            fieldLabel: 'second line',
            labelWidth: 100,
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                flex: 1
            }]
        }
    ]
});
```

If you want to do it dynamically you can do :

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'FieldContainer Example',
    width: 550,
    bodyPadding: 10,

    addRow : function(rowLabel) {
        this.add({
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            fieldLabel: rowLabel,
            labelWidth: 100,
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                flex: 1
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

and then in your loop you can use :

```
myPanel.addRow('test');
```

Comment: You are forgetting the dynamic part. I ALREADY have a panel on the page and I need to just add two textfields inside it in hbox layout depending upon the number of fields in the json data. Are you suggesting that instead of creating a panel before and then adding a container inside it you want me to add the panel completely at run time? Also can you please elaborate why you thought in this way? Is my concept wrong that I get the id of the panel and add to its items list a container ?

Comment: No you were using the right concept (create a panel and then use the add method to insert new element). This is just a layout problem to display the elements the way you want. I have updated my example with dynamic items.

Comment: To access your panel you can either use `Ext.getCmp('panelid')` or if you are in a controller use a ref which is a better practice. (see the "Using refs" section in the API for for Ext.app.Controller).

Comment: Thanx for the help. I found the solution as to why my existing textfields were being replaced by the new ones. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

What version of ExtJS are you using for this example? 3, 4 or 5? I ask this because changes the solution of your problem (more or less) depending on the version.

**EDIT**

Seems that you found a solution. I don't know if you are doing this in the view, but if that's the case, you should use a controller linked to that particular view. In this way your code will look better, more clear and another important reason, the following versions of ExtJS(5), use this kind of structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should use different names for each field too, to be able to retrieve the form values later.

```
name: 'Data' + i
```

**EDIT**

Besides, I would use itemId instead of id, as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18472598/2085604

You can then use Ext.ComponentQuery.query(..) to get components by their itemId:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24407896/2085604

Comment: I had already updated my post with this solution. But thanks for the help.